# I work in a field - who am I?

Tags: riddle

I work in a field 
My flower has four petals 
In fiction I'm gilded 
My heart's made of metal

**Who am I?**

**Edit:** although @deepthought solved the riddle pretty quickly without additional help, here's a second verse I had prepared with more clues for those interested:

> My friend makes the rules 
>  We're good at construction 
>  And oft used as tools 
>  Please resume your deduction

Comment: You are a CPU `:P`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> compass

You work in a

> magnetic

field, your flower

> the compass rose

has four petals

> north/east/south/west

In fiction you are gilded

> "The Golden Compass"

and your heart

> the needle

is made of metal.

Nice riddle!